# Line of best fit in python not working in np.poly

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data:

```
index  value
0      0.054750
1      0.056080
2      0.054581
3      0.055538
4      0.054220
5      0.055983
6      0.055076
7      0.056457
8      0.055801
9      0.058590
10     0.057776
11     0.058401
12     0.057710
13     0.058475
14     0.057733
15     0.058544
16     0.057669
17     0.058636
18     0.055729
19     0.056542
20     0.055288
21     0.057513
22     0.055478
23     0.056832
24     0.055662
25     0.057463
26     0.056061
27     0.057150
28     0.055489
29     0.056153
30     0.055440
31     0.056459
32     0.055495
33     0.056074
34     0.051947
35     0.052471
36     0.051365
37     0.052130
38     0.050143
39     0.051065
40     0.049823
41     0.050748
42     0.050194
43     0.051571
44     0.050630
45     0.051550
46     0.050633
47     0.051225
48     0.049213
49     0.049800
50     0.047450
51     0.047967
52     0.046089
53     0.046614
54     0.045869
55     0.046389
56     0.043600
57     0.044058
58     0.042644
59     0.043088
60     0.042432
61     0.044462
62     0.044004
63     0.044520
64     0.043958
65     0.045231
66     0.043878
67     0.044770
68     0.041983
69     0.043554
70     0.042266
71     0.042952
72     0.042275
73     0.043111
74     0.042613
75     0.045218
76     0.044240
77     0.045816
78     0.044843
79     0.045667
80     0.045153
81     0.046365
82     0.044266
83     0.046175
84     0.044743
85     0.045395
86     0.044432
87     0.046279
88     0.045466
89     0.046025
90     0.044993
91     0.045781
92     0.045281
93     0.046545
94     0.046055
95     0.046671
96     0.045429
97     0.046925
98     0.046089
99     0.048452
100    0.047817
101    0.048625
102    0.047365
103    0.047939
104    0.047024
105    0.047938
106    0.045757
107    0.046229
108    0.045146
109    0.045690
110    0.044868
111    0.045345
112    0.044840
113    0.045632
114    0.045049
115    0.046646
116    0.045883
117    0.046402
118    0.045568
119    0.046266
120    0.045573
121    0.047453
122    0.046485
123    0.047032
124    0.046137
125    0.046820
126    0.046046
127    0.046559
128    0.044865
129    0.045340
130    0.044100
131    0.044957
132    0.042932
133    0.044077
134    0.042693
135    0.043233
136    0.042475
137    0.043441
138    0.042943
139    0.043730
140    0.043247
141    0.043802
142    0.042390
143    0.042930
144    0.042000
145    0.042794
146    0.041531
147    0.042826
148    0.042141
149    0.042625
150    0.041950
151    0.043195
152    0.042384
153    0.042830
154    0.041702
155    0.042422
156    0.040742
157    0.041174
158    0.040692
159    0.041604
160    0.040987
161    0.041706
162    0.040776
163    0.041920
164    0.039951
165    0.040641
166    0.040017
167    0.041296
168    0.039776
169    0.040888
170    0.040428
171    0.041549
172    0.041102
173    0.041701
```

Q:
I want to get a line of best fit  between these values, and afterwards get the average distance the points have from this line. How do I do this?

I have tried:

```
b, m = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
r_x = x
r_y = b + m * x
```

and

```
fit = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
fit_fn = np.poly1d( fit )
```

where `x = index`, `y = value` but I get a line going upwards instead of down.

Expected result:

A line starting roughly `0.055` and finishing about `0.041` ( guessing these values, could be off a bit )

Comment: What do you mean by `best fit line`?

Comment: line that goes through the data with the minimum average distance from the points

Comment: @user2330270: Did you find out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things work as expected for me. I am not sure how you are reading in the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('data.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='data')
plt.plot(x, fit(x), '-b', label='fit')
plt.legend(frameon=False, fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

The distance of each point from the line can be computed as

```
distance = fit(x) - y
```

and the average distance will then be

```
average_distance = np.average(distance)
# -1.1166036167207034e-17
```

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? It’s a direct answer to the question